# Cover term for objects/functions/relations on a domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a convenient technical term that summarizes "objects from and functions and relations on a given domain"?

As in, "A FOL structure consists of a domain of objects and an interpretation function which assigns each non-logical symbol an element of SOMETHING over the domain" where

$$\text{"SOMETHING"} = \quad\mathcal{D}\quad
 \cup\quad
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{D}^{(\mathcal{D}^n)}\quad
 \cup\quad
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \wp(\mathcal{D}^n)$$

i.e. the collection of all elements of $\mathcal{D}$, functions of arbitrary arity on $\mathcal{D}$ and relations of arbitrary arity on $\mathcal{D}$.

The closest that comes to my mind is "data structures on $\mathcal{D}$", but that sounds more like programming and probably also subsumes more than intended.

I can't recall ever having seen a convenient word for this so I guess it doesn't exist, but perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: "Data structures" sounds wrong to me: it is unnatural to think of addition (say) as a data structure. Why do you need a portmanteau term for this concept? Note that the collection of these things for a given structure does have a name: it is the *atomic diagram* of the structure.

Comment: Isn't the atomic diagram the set of atomic or negated atomic sentences that are true in a structure? - That's  not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm hoping such a word would make it easier to talk about an interpretation of a structure.